# A Duplicate file functions differently than original

Tags: java, io, copy, byte

I have a Java jar file wrapped in an executable. It works perfectly fine when double-clicked.

I tried copying the file byte-by-byte and rewriting it to a new executable.

When I try to run this new copy, I get an error message box : [image: File not compatable]

The code I used to copy the bytes of the file is as follows :

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Exec {

    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception {

        byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Dziugas\\Desktop\\Darts.exe"));

        File x = new File("C:\\Users\\Dziugas\\Desktop\\file.exe");

        if(!x.exists())
            x.createNewFile();

        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(x, true));

        for(byte b: data)
            writer.write(b);

        writer.close();

    }


}
```

The size of the copy is the same as original. This makes me wonder about Java's I/O API.. I thought read all bytes meant exactly that?

I tried deleting the copy and running the code again, but the error persisted. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the file as a stream of bytes, implicitly casting them to `char`s, then writing the `char`s. Use `OutputStream`s to write bytes (and `InputStream`s to read bytes). Use `Writer`s and `Reader`s to write and read `char`s.

In general, if you have a byte array, then converting it to chars and back could completely mangle it. For example, your example *might* (depending on the platform) result in the file getting encoded as UTF-8.

Comment: Doe the conversion to char apply to all byte streams or just the method in the Files class?

Comment: @Dziugas It applies to neither byte streams nor `Files`. It's *your code*, which calls `Writer.write(char)` with a `byte` (implicitly casting the byte to a char).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
Path pathFrom = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Dziugas\\Desktop\\Darts.exe");
Path pathTo = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Dziugas\\Desktop\\file.exe");
Files.copy(pathFrom, pathTo, StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES);
```